# Throw Exception then Call Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

So I'm building a test library that I will mainly use for personal use however I have a question.

With Java, if you have 2 or more constructors in your class, if you wish to call one from another, it must be the first thing you do. This is problematic for me as I have the below setup.

```
public Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
    if (c.getData() == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    this(a, b, c.getOtherData());
}

public Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeD d) {
    // stuff happens
}
```

How can I do this, avoiding the, "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor" error?

Comment: You cannot do what you want.

Comment: Instead of a constructor consider a static factory method.

Comment: I believe that is not a very good design.
IllegalArgumentException is thrown to indicate that the constructor was used incorrectly, that is fine. However, the constructor itself should not handle its own exception. Instead, the code that called this construction should handle it and call the other constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with constructors. Instead use a static factory method like this:

```
public static TypeThing buildMyThing(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
    if (c.getData() == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    return new TypeThing(a, b, c.getOtherData());
}

public Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeD d) {
    // stuff happens
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**One option (probably bad):**
Check for `getData == null and throw the exception as first thing in`c.getOtherData()`. That would be the first method being executed.

**Other Option:**
Have a method like,

```
helper() {
    if (getData() == null) throw new Exception();
    return getOtherData();
}
```

and from you constructor, call `c.helper()` instead of `c.getOtherData()`

Comment: For your second option you should make helper final to avoid "Overridable method call in constructor" issues.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a static factory method?

```
public static Constructor newInstance(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
    if (c.getData() == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    return new Constructor(a, b, c);
}

private Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
    this(a, b, c.getOtherData());
}

private Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeD d) {
    // stuff happens
}
```

Comment: In that, why wouldn't you just scrap the first constructor and have the factory method return the second constructor?

Comment: @Spedwards I wasn't sure how exactly you were using the first constructor so I didn't want to remove it, but if you think that's viable, then you can certainly do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an additional private construtor. Im assuming you've simplified the code a bit too much here. You are saying if something is null then throw - else you something else.

```
public Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC c) {
   this(a, b, c.getData(), c.getOtherData()); //calls the private ctor
}

public Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeD d) {
    // stuff happens  
}

private Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeD d1, TypeD d2) {
    // stuff happens  
}
```

or you could just pass in TypeC

```
 private Constructor(TypeA a, TypeB b, TypeC) {
    // now do you null check here.
}
```

Java does cause some pains sometimes! and then *this* rule is one of them. In specific answer to your question about the compile error - you cant :(

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the exception thrown to the beginning of the second constructor. That will achieve the exact same thing. If there are multiple paths to that constructor, you could make an additional parameter that signals logical path.

Comment: I can't do this... Once I call `c.getOtherData()`, I lose `c.getData()`

Comment: In that case, it looks like you're just using getData() as a boolean marker in this particular instance. You might want to add a boolean parameter to the lowest constructor marking whether getData was null. when calling it, it would look like this:

Comment: Constructor(a, b, c.GetData() == null, c.GetOtherData())